# MAAS 2.0.0 - Extra Data when adding subnet

Tags: maas

I've seen this error on another post here, but can't comment on it. The error I'm getting when trying to add a subnet is "Extra data: line 1 column 6 (char 5)". I've attempted multiple ways to put this in, with one dns, with two, untagged and tagged, with a Name and without, same results.

[image]

Just tried this again and tailed `/var/log/syslog`, python errors!

```
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: 2016-06-23 13:12:12 [-] Error on request (51) subnet.create: Extra data: line 1 column 6 (char 5)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011Traceback (most recent call last):
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/provisioningserver/utils/twisted.py", line 841, in worker
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    return target()
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/_threads/_threadworker.py", line 46, in work
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    task()
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/_threads/_team.py", line 190, in doWork
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    task()
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011--- <exception caught here> ---
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 246, in inContext
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    result = inContext.theWork()
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 262, in <lambda>
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    inContext.theWork = lambda: context.call(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    return func(*args,**kw)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/provisioningserver/utils/twisted.py", line 874, in callInContext
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    return func(*args, **kwargs)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/maasserver/utils/orm.py", line 516, in call_within_transaction
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    return func_outside_txn(*args, **kwargs)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/maasserver/utils/orm.py", line 343, in retrier
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    return func(*args, **kwargs)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    return func(*args, **kwds)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/maasserver/websockets/base.py", line 380, in create
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    obj.save()
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/maasserver/models/cleansave.py", line 28, in save
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    self.full_clean()
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1149, in full_clean
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    self.clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/maasserver/models/subnet.py", line 389, in clean_fields
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    super().clean_fields(*args, **kwargs)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1191, in clean_fields
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self))
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 587, in clean
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    value = self.to_python(value)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/contrib/postgres/fields/array.py", line 88, in to_python
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    vals = json.loads(value)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 6 (char 5)
Jun 23 13:12:12 usw1maas001 sh[11770]: #011
```

Comment: No one can answer this? Tried deploying MAAS on Ubuntu 16.04 again yesterday and ran into the same issue.

Comment: One thing I'm learning is that MAAS Network is VERY picky about what steps are done... still trying to iron this out. But a new problem arises - can only select the Rack Controller for one VLAN. I have an AIO (Region and Rack controller) setup, but can't seem to have the Rack controller portion assigned to more than one VLAN as other VLANs I'm trying assign it to have nothing to select... very concerned about this - is this by design?

Comment: Ran into this issue again - this time I've followed through what worked last time: Create Fabric, create VLAN, create Space, then create Subnet - This last part keeps throwing a data error. This worked just fine a couple days ago, until I threw a Rack Controller into the mix - I keep running into tiny little issues with these provisioning tools that are called "stable," "mature," etc, etc.... I want an easy way to control the crazy with multiple data centers, but these tiny issues (and no one answering questions) are killing us.

https://jpst.it/KPLa